# How change email template language in Chinese for odoo10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, email-templates

I want to change e-mail template language in Chinese(HK). But it is not reflected. So, Anyone suggest how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to pass lang filed in your template and after converting from preference in mail template it got current lang.

Comment: Hello Keval, Can you explain? Can i create new po file in i18 directory for customization of language.

Answer (score 0):

after to load translation (chinese), Go to **Administrator > Preferences >** Language 
And choice the **chinese Language** 
**> Save**

Comment: It is not reflected in email-template. And if email-template is designed then also not converted.